# Unit testing a function that returns a generator object

Tags: python

The title pretty much sums it up: I tried to use assertEqual to test a function that returns a generator object, but that results in:

> AssertionError: generator object genexpr> at 0x2e70c80> != (1,2,...)

Is there a clever way to do this other than iterating over the function and running assertEqual for each individual output?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
assertEqual(tuple(generator_object), (1, 2, ...))
```

if it's an infinite generator, or you just wish to look at the first `n` results for some reason, you can combint this with `itertools.islice`

```
assertEqual(tuple(islice(generator_object, n)), (1, 2, ...))
```

Comment: This is what I like about Python, there is always an easier (cleaner) way to do things. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `next()` on the generator object.

```
assertEqual(next(generator_object), (1, 2, ...))
```

Comment: The single call to next will return one value, so you would have to call assertEqual on each expected value. `assertEqual(next(generator), 1)`