# Write unittest for function with yield

Tags: python, unit-testing, generator

I am trying to write a unittest for a function that utilizes a generator. Below is my code:

```
def extract_data(body):
    for i in body:
        a = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', str(i))
        b = re.sub('view\xc2\xa0book\xc2\xa0info', '', str(a))
        c = re.sub('key', '', str(b))
        d = re.sub('\xc2', ' ', str(c))
        e = re.sub('\xa0', '', str(d))
        yield e
```

My unittest code:

```
    def test_extract_data(self):
        sample_input = ['<tr><h1>keyThis</h1><h2>\xc2</h2><h3>\xa0</h3><h4>view\xc2\xa0book\xc2\xa0info</h4><h5>Test Passes</h5></tr>']
        expected_res = 'This Test Passes'
        res = extract_data(sample_input)

        self.assertEqual(expected_res, res)
```

This test passes without issue if the extract_data function uses a return instead of yield. How do I write the test for the generator?

Comment: Aside from the question you're asking, you really shouldn't be using regular expressions to try to parse HTML (It's impossible to do in the general case). There's a really good library that can do this for you that I would strongly encourage you to use: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775794/unit-testing-a-function-that-returns-a-generator-object

Comment: @Lefty has your question been answered?

Comment: @Kyle_Falconer, thanks for the tip. I'm not a fan of using regular expressions for parsing HTML, however in this specific case it works best.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured out what I needed to do. I needed to make the res into a list. and that was it. A lot simpler than I expected. so this is what it looks like now:

```
class TestScrapePage(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_extract_data(self):
        sample_input = ['<tr><h1>keyThis</h1><h2>\xc2</h2><h3>\xa0</h3><h4>view\xc2\xa0book\xc2\xa0info</h4><h5>Test Passes</h5></tr>']
        expected_res = ['This Test Passes']
        res = list(extract_data(sample_input))

    self.assertEqual(expected_res, res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code, slightly altered to not require unittest:

```
import re

def extract_data(body):
    for i in body:
        a = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', str(i))
        b = re.sub('view\xc2\xa0book\xc2\xa0info', '', str(a))
        c = re.sub('key', '', str(b))
        d = re.sub('\xc2', ' ', str(c))
        e = re.sub('\xa0', '', str(d))
        yield e

def test_extract_data():
    sample_input = ['<tr><h1>keyThis</h1><h2>\xc2</h2><h3>\xa0</h3><h4>view\xc2\xa0book\xc2\xa0info</h4><h5>Test Passes</h5></tr>']
    expected_res = 'This Test Passes'
    res = extract_data(sample_input)
    return expected_res == res

print(test_extract_data())
```

This prints `False`

The problem is that when you do `return`, the function, in your case, returns a `str`. However, when you do `yield`, it returns a `generator` type object whose `next()` function returns a `str`. So, for example:

```
import re

def extract_data(body):
    for i in body:
        a = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', str(i))
        b = re.sub('view\xc2\xa0book\xc2\xa0info', '', str(a))
        c = re.sub('key', '', str(b))
        d = re.sub('\xc2', ' ', str(c))
        e = re.sub('\xa0', '', str(d))
        yield e

def test_extract_data():
    sample_input = ['<tr><h1>keyThis</h1><h2>\xc2</h2><h3>\xa0</h3><h4>view\xc2\xa0book\xc2\xa0info</h4><h5>Test Passes</h5></tr>']
    expected_res = 'This Test Passes'
    res = extract_data(sample_input)
    return expected_res == next(res)

print(test_extract_data())
```

This prints `True`.

To illustrate, at the [Python command prompt](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html):

```
>>> type("hello")
<class 'str'>
>>> def gen():
...     yield "hello"
... 
>>> type(gen())
<class 'generator'>
```

Your other option (possibly better, depending on your use case), is to test that are all of the results of the `generator` are correct by converting the `generator` object's results into a `list` or `tuple`, and then compare for equality:

```
import re

def extract_data(body):
    for i in body:
        a = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', str(i))
        b = re.sub('view\xc2\xa0book\xc2\xa0info', '', str(a))
        c = re.sub('key', '', str(b))
        d = re.sub('\xc2', ' ', str(c))
        e = re.sub('\xa0', '', str(d))
        yield e

def test_extract_data():
    sample_input = ['<tr><h1>keyThis</h1><h2>\xc2</h2><h3>\xa0</h3><h4>view\xc2\xa0book\xc2\xa0info</h4><h5>Test Passes</h5></tr>', '<tr><h1>keyThis</h1><h2>\xc2</h2><h3>\xa0</h3><h4>view\xc2\xa0book\xc2\xa0info</h4><h5>Test Passes Too!</h5></tr>']
    expected_res = ['This Test Passes', 'This Test Passes Too!']
    res = extract_data(sample_input)
    return expected_res == list(res)

print(test_extract_data())
```

Comment: I believe you mean `next(expected_res) == res` in your second snippet.

Comment: @michael_j_ward Thanks for the catch! Almost. `expected_res` is a `str`, so the next goes on the `res` -- :-)